# Throw An exception from the UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The main UI thread is showing a popup dialog (Form). I would like to force the UI thread to close this popup dialog and throw an exception to the UI thread (from another thread) when an abort request is received.

Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe you can use SynchronizationContext.

Comment: Why can't you just use a dispatcher to close the popup dialog?

Comment: Exceptions don't cross thread boundaries.  You have to use Control.BeginInvoke() to run code on the UI thread.  Which certainly can close a dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't throw an exception.  An exception can't be caught be a different thread.  Expose a public method that will call close on your form:

```
DlgForm.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(Close));
```

and set an 'aborted' state flag that the UI can use after the dialog closes.